# Adding a resolver (Maven repo) to Play Framework 2.1-RC4 project?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to add a resolver to my Play 2.1-RC4 build file and getting the error "not found: value resolvers"

Any ideas what's going wrong?

```
import sbt._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val appName = "myappname"
val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.ocpsoft.prettytime" % "prettytime" % "2.1.2.Final",
    "com.twitter" % "cassie" % "0.19.0",
    jdbc,
    anorm)


val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultScalaSettings: _*).settings(
    resolvers += "Twitter's Repository" at "http://maven.twttr.com/"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
import Keys._
import PlayProject._
```